# populate select box jquery, php and chosen plugin

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using Chosen plugin, php and jquery to populate a select box with data from database.

Once the user click on the select box :

```
$("#mabranche").next().bind('click', function () {
//get data from database
})
```

Everything is going well, the data is shown :
[image: data shown when the user click on the select box]

But when i choose one of the items (after Debugging the code), the above function is called again.

I tried also to use

```
$('#mabranche').live('focus', function() {
//get data from database
})
```

But it work as the same way as the other example (even if i choose one item, the select box dont lose the focus and call again the function)

there is a way to manage this problem?

Comment: unbind the click in the function **.unbind('click')**

Comment: if i unbind the click, the event will never work

Comment: if i get this right... you have this box and you want to select a element to get data for this element ?

Comment: @Dwza no it's not that, i want when the user click on the select box, load data from database and show it in the select box like above and after choose one item from the list

Comment: in selected event in your select box use `.focus()` event to set focus to the next element

Comment: @Mr-Moqadam  where i have to use .focus() ? after the user choose an item ?

Comment: @MehdiBoussarhane : Yes. like this : `$('.selectbox').change(function(){
$(this).next().focus()`
});

Comment: i still have the same problem

Comment: please insert your code